# how to affect two elements(image1 and image2) by clicking on image3

Tags: html, css

I have a school project where **I can't use Javascript.** Just `HTML` and `CSS`.
The theme is `Lucky Luke`, and I'm trying to make an animation, where he shoots whenever I click another object.

The idea is to have two images on top of each other, where one goes invisible, and the other one goes visible whenever I shoot an object, where the object I click on is the trigger.

The two images should then go back to their original state of opacity after a short period time.

```css
#luckyStand {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -250px;
}

#luckyShoot {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -250px;
}

#db1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  right: 370px;
}

#db1:target~#luckyShoot {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="db1">
  <a href="#db1">
    <img src="images/dalton_brother1.png">
  </a>
</div>

<div id="luckyStand">
  <img src="images/lucky_luke_idle.png">
</div>

<div id="luckyShoot">
  <img src="images/lucky_luke_shooting.png">
</div>
```

Comment: can you use javascript :p (Java and Javscript are completely different languages)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a [keyframes animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes):

```css
#luckyShoot {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: 2s;         /* length of time to show the element before it disappears again */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#db1:target~#luckyShoot {
  animation-name: fadeInOut;
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;  /* will show immediately */
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 1;  /* for 99% of the animation duration (2s) */
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;  /* will hide at the end */
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="db1">
  <a href="#db1">
    <img src="images/dalton_brother1.png">
  </a>
</div>

<div id="luckyStand">
  shown
</div>

<div id="luckyShoot">
  start hidden
</div>
```